# Conflict in compilation of Java Code on Window xp

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I was trying to go stone-age on Java and decided to run programs without the use of IDE. Soon, I found myself looking at a program which needed me to import an external jar file. I did face some problems but thanks to my ever faithful sidekick (Stackoverflow.com) I overcame them all and Wham!! executed my program.

Now, all of a sudden this query strike me brain. Will the same code run on windows xp too(I sincerely dont know why that would occur to me). So by placing the trust on my ever sidekick I embarked upon the journey.Here is the overview of what I did:

1. VMware --->> XP ---->> JDK Latest Download -->> Run Setup --->>

   set Path = C/Programs/1.7/bin and CLASSPATH = "C:\Program Files         (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext" (both are set as Enviromental
   variables) -->>Copied and pasted the external jar file into the CLASSPATH directory -->> cmd -->> javac Myclass.java -->> compiled and .class file created at the same loaction as my Java file --->> java Myclass -->> couldnot find or load main class --->> java -cp . Myclass -->> NoclassdefFoundError .

Now the thing that baffles my is that the i did the same thing with the same code(same imports, jar ,everything) in windows 7 and it did copile and did gimme the output then why is it acting like a jerk in XP? Please Help.

Code is Quite Simple :

```
    import com.gesmallworld.core.acp.AcptAcp;
```

public class AcpE1 extends AcptAcp {

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
 {

        System.out.println("Hello World");
 }
```

}

P.S: I tried to compile the code by removing the "extends AcptAcp" and found that it result in error free output on xp.

Comment: If you extend to some class (AcptAcp here) you need to put that class (or the containing jar) into your classpath too.

Comment: @Jeff does different rules apply for windows 7 and XP cuz as I said I followed the exact same steps which I tried in Windows7 and it did compile.. same code..same jar..same import..same everything.. Also as i said I have added the "jre\ext" into the classpath variable and then went ahead and copied the required jar file into the ext folder.. So by theory it should work right?

Comment: Did you set the classpath correctly? Check this out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you confuse. In Windows XP or Windows 7 , every java programs will run easily, and the results are the same.I suggest you to learn Java Packages and CLASSPATH behaviors. Read [this](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J9c_PackageClasspath.html) and after finished to read this article and you will solve your problem.

Comment: I am not confused my friend.. I suggest you do re-read my post.. I know that there is no difference between running a java program in WIndows xp , 7 , 8 or 9236363 for that matter.. And since i do have this knowledge, it baffles me as to why the same code which ran in my windows 7 with the same settings failed to run in xp